# Nvidia GTX - 3 Monitors - Can only enable 2

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have an Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti.  I have three monitors connected.  Up until today all three worked perfectly.  I had some type of GUI freeze/bug.  So I just did a simple shutdown restart.

Now I can only get two monitors enabled.  I have to turn the third monitor off.  If I turn on all three monitors (physically) and then go into display settings to try to enable a second or third monitor, the GUI says that "changes cannot be applied" possible due to "hardware limitations".  (Note that with all three monitors physically turned on, the logon screen displays its background wallpaper on all three monitors).

I have also tried using the nvidia-settings application to enable the monitors with no luck.

I am using the Nvidia 435.21 drivers. Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that Nvidia driver 430+ are still not stable releases. I think the most stable one is 418.

Try auto-installing with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

My second monitor stopped displaying anything after a shutdown a few days ago. I was using Gnome desktop, but I installed KDE desktop and the monitor started working again in KDE, then it worked again when I switched back to Gnome. I've looked through a lot of other threads for NVIDIA and second monitor issues, and someone else had success by switching to LightDM and back. I know this isn't a direct answer but it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem "changes cannot be applied due to hardware configuration" under Ubuntu 22.10 and using four monitors with an Nvidia NVS 510 graphics card.  I discovered that making changes one at a time for instance changing the resolution of one monitor, then applying, then changing the position of one monitor (I have three monitors superimposed because we are livestreaming to a projector and two other destinations) then applying, each change is incremental.  Eventually I find one change that doesn't work - one of my monitors does not support a particular resolution in my case, then I adjust other monitors resolution to match what can I can achive with the least capable.